# How to automatically tessellate a triangle's edge at T-vertices

Tags: blender, meshlab

My 3D mesh contains T-vertices. I want to keep all vertices, but automatically subdivide triangles's edges that run through/past such a vertex.
Here's an

image showing triangles with t-vertices, and after the tessellation

[image: 1]

that I'm looking for.

I started implementing some code but really think this must already exist.

Answer (score 0):

The question is if your input mesh consist on plain triangles (in which case you can't have neighbors, because you can have several neighbors by each edge) or your mesh consist on "triangle shaped polygons".

If your input are triangles, meshlab won't solve your problem.

If you have polygons, you can use the "convert mesh into pure triangles" filter.

Comment: As I said, the input is triangles with T-vertices, so Meshlab's conversion into triangles won't work.
I think for every edge, all other vertices on the edge must be found (within a small distance of the edge), sorted along the edge, and inserted into the vertex list of the respective faces.